# Is there a way to prevent calls to a specific inherited function in a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, member, virtual-functions

Consider the following:

```
class base {

    // base class

public:
    void doBaseStuff() {
        /* do something basic */
    }
private:
    int someDataMember;
};

class derived : public base {

    // this class inherits 'doBaseStuff()' as well as 'someDataMember'

public:
    void doDerivedStuff() {
        /* do something in addition that only this type of derived class can do */
    }
};

class specialDerived : public base {

    // say 'doBaseStuff()' doesn't make sense in the context of this class!
    // we do not want to inherit that function here
    // is there a way to prevent instances of this class from calling it?
    // we still want 'someDataMember', so we must derive from the base class

public:
    void doSpecialStuff() {
        /* do something in addition that only this special derived class can do */
    }
};
```

There's a class that serves as a common base class for multiple other classes. But let's say one of the base class' member functions it NOT wanted in one of the derived classes. Is there a way to explicitly ban an inherited function in a derived class?

Realisticly we could be talking about a base class that has a 1000 members, and we want to inherit 999 of them, so simply abandoning inheritance and just duplicating all the code will result in very bad code maintainability.

Making that function in the base class virtual, and providing a dummy implementation of it in the `specialDerived` class would work. But what if that function has an actual return type, instead of `void`? The `specialDerived` class would then have to provide an implementation that returns something. The caller then could assume that the value they got is something meaningful, when it's really not, and that's a problem.

Simply implementing the virtual function in `specialDerived` with a single `throw` in the body could be a solution, as long as some documentation exists that explicitly states that calling this function on objects of this specific derived type has no meaning, and that this operation will throw. I think this is one possible solution, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go.

Comment: You can't prevent calls of a non-virtual function you inherit. For that matter you can't prevent calls of the base class implementation of a public member function. But you can simply abstain from inheriting.

Comment: The problem is that the actual base class in my code has a ton of functions and data members. Copying all that into a new class (except for a minor part of it) would make maintenance very hard, since any change I make would have to be applied to the other class as well. That's why I wanted to inherit (most) stuff from my base class.

Comment: Inheritance is an `is-a` relationship, if one (or more) of its operations does not make sense for you clearly this is not an `is-a` relationship, so your problem is you shouldn't be inheriting in the first place.

Comment: If the function you wanted to "hide" was virtual then you could hide it in the derived class simply by overriding it with a function that does nothing.

Comment: @adam10603 Implement proper ***interfaces*** in 1st place! No matter if you're using dynamic (pure virtual functions) or static (lookup CRTP) polymorphism. As is, your design is seriously flawed.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, but what if the function I wish to hide has a return type? Then the empty implementation would have to return something, and the caller then could assume that what they received is something meaningful, but it's really not.

Comment: What if I make the function virtual in the base class, and the derived class that does not want that function would simply implement it to throw an exception? And I would state in the documentation that calling that function on this specific derived type has no meaning, and will result in an exception. Is this something reasonable to do?

Comment: @adam10603 If you cannot return something reasonable, throw an exception instead. We cannot tell if that is _wrong behavior_ in general, that totally depends on your actual use case.

Comment: Throwing an exception would seem an appropriate response.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I think I'll go with that then.

Comment: @adam10603 I'd rather go for a static polymorphism concept that bails out at compilation phase, than throwing an exception at runtime.

Comment: @adam10603: make a start at refactoring by factoring out the stuff you need as a base class of the existing Octopus class. Then inherit only from that, or have it as a member.

Comment: It's really rare I'm upvoting a question like this. Not sure if it's really too broad, or could be solved with a common idiom/pattern (which is likely leading to a duplicate, I don't have at hand).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: right. in this case it looks like a known **anti-pattern**, the [*God-object* anti-pattern](https://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/05/28/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-monster-objects/). And the solution (the anti-anti-pattern) is refactoring. As I already suggested.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's a really good point in this case! Probably answers the question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf /OT Obviously both of us refrain from answering such questions (for my part it's most because I _feel limited_ from my tablet). In general we should more use LRIO's _"braze faced"_ answering style, instead of sticking with the OPs misconceptions.

Comment: "God-object " doesn't really apply in my case. The base class in my case is very much limited to one single functionality, but needs a number of members to achieve it. It's not really composed of stuff that could be referred to as this "and" that. It only serves one very specific purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to make sure the method is not called accidentially, i.e. a compilation error when it gets called is perfect.

You can simply override `doBaseStuff` in `specialDerived` with a deleted definition:

```
class specialDerived : public base {
  void doBaseStuff() = delete;

public:
  void doSpecialStuff() {
      /* do something in addition that only this special derived class can do */
  }
};
```

That will prevent anyone from using `specialDerived::doBaseStuff`.  It is still possible to convert a reference to `specialDerived` to a reference to `base` and call `doBaseStuff` on the result, but that can't be avoided without making `doBaseStuff` `virtual`.

Comment: In my case, overriding a virtual function with a `throw` in the body makes more sense, but I'm still accepting this as an answer, since I didn't really provide much detail about my specific case. My question was very general, and this does in fact answer it. In my case however, I'm just going to throw whenever this happens. But thanks anyway! Anyone else could find this useful, since it does in fact work, so I'm leaving this as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare `doBaseStuff` protected in `base`
2. Derive a new class `base2` from `base` which just makes `doBaseStuff` public
3. Derive the 999 classes from `base2` instead of `base`
4. Derive the one class from `base`

Like so:

```
class base {
protected:
    void doBaseStuff() {
        /* do something basic */
    }
private:
    int someDataMember;
};

class base2 : public base {
public:
    using base::doBaseStuff; // make it public
};

class derived : public base2 {
   // ...
};

class specialDerived : public base {
   // doBaseStuff not public here since we're derived only from base (and not base2) and didn't make it public ourself
};
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to make `doBaseStuff()` protected in `base`. One could simply move it completely to `base2()` most of the cases.

Comment: Sometimes one can, sometimes one cannot :) I wanted to show how the less trivial version, where one can not, looks like. (Also I have personally encountered that less trivial version more often than the trivial one.)