# allow access to some methods only to direct children

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a type `Test` with a `print()` method and another type `SubTest` which inherits from `Test`.

Now I have a new type `SubSubTest` which inherits from `SubTest`.
Is it possible to prevent `SubSubTest` from accessing the `print()` method of Test but allow `SubTest` to access it?
Basically, allow access to some methods only to direct children.
All this will be done with CRTP classes so no virtual functions.

```
class Test {
protected:
        void print() {
                std::cout << "in Test" << std::endl;
        }
};

class SubTest: public Test {
        void print() {
                Test::print();
        }
};

class SubSubTest: public SubTest {
        void print() {
                Test::print(); // error not allowed
        }
};
```

**EDIT:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum class Type {
        whatever,
};

template <typename T>
class SSLsocket;

struct Socket {
        void send(char *buff, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "Socket send" << std::endl;
        }
        void on_message(char *buff, int size);
        Type type; // public for simplicity
private:
        template <typename T>
        void dispath_message(SSLsocket<T> *sock, char *buff, int size);

        int fd;
};

template <typename T>
class SSLsocket
{
public:
        void send(char *buff, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "SSLsocket send" << std::endl;
                socket.send(buff, size);
        }

private:
        friend Socket;
        void on_message(char *buff, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "SSLsocket on_message" << std::endl;
                reinterpret_cast<T *>(this)->on_message(buff, size);
        }

private:
        Socket socket;
};

template <typename T>
class websocket : public SSLsocket<websocket<T>>
{
public:
        void send(char *buffer, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "websocket send" << std::endl;
                SSLsocket<websocket<T>>::send(buffer, size);
        }

private:
        friend SSLsocket<websocket<T>>;
        void on_message(char *buff, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "websocket on_message" << std::endl;
                reinterpret_cast<T *>(this)->on_message(buff, size);
        }
};

class whatever : public websocket<whatever>
{
public:
        void send(char *buffer, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "whatever send" << std::endl;
                websocket<whatever>::send(buffer, size);

                // MUST BE IMPOSSIBLE
                // SSLsocket<websocket<whatever>>::send(buffer, size);
        }

private:
        friend websocket<whatever>;
        void on_message(char *buff, int size)
        {
                std::cout << "whatever on_message" << std::endl;
                send(nullptr, 0);
        }
};

void Socket::on_message(char *buff, int size)
{
        std::cout << "socket on_message" << std::endl;
        switch (type) {
        case Type::whatever: {
                auto *w = reinterpret_cast<whatever *>(this);
                dispath_message(w, buff, size);
                break;
        }
        }
}

template <typename T>
void Socket::dispath_message(SSLsocket<T> *sock, char *buff, int size)
{
        sock->on_message(buff, size);
}


int main()
{
        // There are no members in the classes so to simplify the example 
        // we only build the socket class which will be cast later.
        Socket sock;
        sock.type = Type::whatever;
        sock.on_message(nullptr, 0);
}
```

The goal is to replace callbacks by direct calls.

The `Socket` type will have to know all the `final` types (like our `whatever` type) to do the first cast.
This is not a recommended practice but there will be very few additions and there is a way to make a clean file with lots of warnings so that every edition is done carefully.

The main problem is that the `whatever` class can directly call the `send` function of the `SSLsocket` class.

**Pipeline:**

The `on_message` function starts from the `Socket` class to the `final` class.

The `send` function goes from the `final` class to the `Socket` class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to prevent calls to a specific inherited function in a derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081438/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-calls-to-a-specific-inherited-function-in-a-derived-cl)

Comment: _"All this will be done with CRTP classes so no virtual functions."_ Please show us your CRTP code.

Comment: @paolo Edit done

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, you can have `SubTest` inherit from `Test` [privately](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Private_inheritance), which in turn means that `SubTest` can see all of `Test`'s `public` and `protected` members, and re-exports them as `private`. This means that `SubSubTest` will not be able to see the members exposed from `Test`.

```cpp
class Test
{
protected:
  void print() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

class SubTest : private Test
{
public:
  void print() { Test::print(); }
};

class SubSubtest : public SubTest
{
public:
  void print() { Test::print(); } // failure 
};
```

**Edit**

Based on your example code, this solution will not work due to you needing to cast your `whatever` type to `SSLsocket<websocket<whatever>>`. In this instance, I would wonder whether CRTP is the right choice for what you're trying to implement; SSLsocket is not enhancing a behaviour of an existing type, but is rather being adapted by other types. In this instance, why not instead treat `websocket` and `whatever` as adapters? In that case, your `SSLsocket` would be a private member variable of `websocket` hence unavailable to `whatever`. Effectively something like so:

```cpp
struct isocket
{
  virtual void send(char *, int) = 0;
  virtual void on_message(char *, int) { }
}

struct fsocket : public isocket
{
  void send(char *data, int length) override { fwrite(fd, data, length); }

private:
  int fd; 
};

template <typename Socket>
struct sslsocket : public isocket
{
  void send(char *data, int length) override { _base.send(...); }
private:
  Socket _base;
};

struct websocket : public isocket
{
  void send(char *data, int length) override { ... };
private:
  sslsocket _base;
};

struct whatever : public isocket
{
  void send(char *data, int length) override { ... };
private:
  websocket _base;
};
```

Comment: `SubSubTest::print` trying to use `Test::print` will be an error due to `SubSubTest` seeing the `Test::print` method privately as a result of the private inheritance from `SubTest`. Removing this would allow the snippet to compile, hence the `failure `comment. Checked against clang++-7

Comment: It won't work, I can't make a cast if the type is private. I edited my question if you want to understand better

Comment: Following your edition. I currently have an implementation that looks like this but the goal here is to make direct calls instead of indirect calls (via virtual functions).

Answer (score 1):

You could declare `print` as `private` in the base class and make class `Subtest` a `friend`:

```
class Test
{
  friend class Subtest;

private:
  void print() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

class SubTest : public Test
{
public:
  void print() { Test::print(); }
};

class SubSubtest : public SubTest
{
public:
  void print() { Test::print(); }
};
```

This does, however, have the disadvantage that `Subtest` can access all the private members of the base class.  That would be soluble if you weren't using CRTP, but as you are it probably isn't.  So, as @paolo says, please post your CRTP code and I'll see if anything can be done.

Comment: Quick note, the statement was that `SubSubTest` should *not* be able to access the CRTP classes members; the adjustment here is that the `friend` should be `SubTest`.

Comment: @mitch_ Whoops!  Corrected, thank you.  Trouble is, your solution hides too much (potentially) and mine too little.

Comment: I thought of this way but I prefer not to do that.